# Android 7.1.1 Wifi Direct can't creat group

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct

After update Huawei Nexus 6P to Android 7.1.1 I can't create a group.

When I call `createGroup()` or `removeGroup()` the system invokes callback `onFailure(int reason)` with message `"2" (busy)`

Before the updated all worked well.

Answer (score 1):

**It's the system error of the android 7.1.1.**

Some devices have been updated to Android 7.1.2 where this error was fixed, another ones now have rollback to the previous version.

Unfortunately it`s impossible to use WIfi direct correctly with Android 7.1.1